# Creating Ideas from inbound emails using Email Services

Tags: apex-email-service

I am using following blog to create idea from inbound email:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Code_Sample_-_Creating_Ideas_from_inbound_emails_using_Email_Services

When I send an email to the email address of Email Service.
I get the below error:

class CreateIdeaFromEmail failed due to: System.DmlException: Insert  failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Zone]: [Zone]

I am not getting how to use Community (Zone) object and assign zone to Idea?

Can someone help on how to fix this error ?

Thanks
Nishant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the communityId field is required. Here's an example of how you'd query for a zone id and assign the id value to the idea before insertion.

```
i.communityId = [SELECT Id FROM Community WHERE Name = 'Test Zone'].Id;
```